# How to access Team Foundation Server (TFS) from Linux

Tags: linux, version-control, tfs

If this question weren't specific to a VCS (and therefore be the kind of thing that programmers would know more about than sys admins) then I'd ask it on server fault or superuser...

That said, how can I access TFS from Linux?  Is there a client app that will run on Linux, or perhaps a TFS-to-SVN bridge that could run on Windows and be accessed via a SVN on Linux?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not free, but if you use Eclipse <strike>[TeamPrise](http://www.teamprise.com/)</strike> Microsoft has a plugin to connect to TFS, [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155781.aspx), download at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661.  There is also a Java-based command line client that should work on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Matlab on Linux, not Eclipse.

Comment: TeamPrise has been aquired by Microsoft and is now available as Team Explorer Everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Team Explorer Everywhere - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-explorer-everywhere

Comment: This looks good. It's a free Eclipse plugin from Microsoft. Can you confirm whether it works on Linux, or does it require native Windows libraries?

Comment: @DrewNoakes http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661#system-requirements

Answer (score 2):

use the TEE-CLC-12.0.0.zip available from MS from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661

its a simple CLC for TFS

Comment: @DrewNoakes It opens for me

Comment: Strange, I see _502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server_ using Chrome on Ubuntu. I'll check it out later. Sounds like a good answer to this question though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"a TFS-to-SVN bridge"? err you should 'check out'... [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The OP asked for a Linux solution, I can't see any support for Linux on that site - could you provide a link?

Comment: "or perhaps a TFS-to-SVN bridge that could run on Windows" - you can run SvnBridge server side (as well as client) and connect with an svn client - http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/releases/view/58343

Comment: Looks like I misread the question, thanks for the clarification :) +1