# Get files from TFS under Linux

Tags: linux, tfs

is there a free (command line) tool for linux which with I can get all files from a TFS-Repository (no Check in / Check out required - only get actual version)?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368458/how-to-access-team-foundation-server-tfs-from-linux

Comment: Will the moderator closed this question incorrectly and it appears from his profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will that his decision was motivated by a desire to suppress information.

Comment: I agree that this question should not have been closed.  Microsoft gives away Team Explorer Everywhere for free.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it, but there is opentf - http://code.google.com/p/opentf/

I think that the Hudson/Jenkins TFS Plugin uses opentf.

Answer (score 0):

[Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com/) have a [command line client](http://www.teamprise.com/products/download/) for accessing TFS

Comment: ...but costs $300 and I do not need all the features it offers. Is there nothing "basic" for free?

Comment: Since the company was bought by Microsoft, the client is now freely available.

Answer (score 0):

You should 'check out'... SvnBridge, it's a free proxy that maps svn client commands to your TFS repository [link text](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)

Comment: svnbridge is a windows solution, the fellow wanted a linux line mode command.